# How to do logging in console application

Tags: c#, logging

I have a simple console application that will be deployed as a scheduled job. Below is its pseudo code

```
Main(string[] args)
{
    //get xml string from database
    Reports reports = ReportsDB.GetReport(args[0].ToString());

    //Generate xml file using xmwriter

    //post the file to sftp site
}
```

I was wondering how to include logging functionality for this job. Also, will it be suffice to use a text writer to write to text file every time it is run or use libraries such as log4net

**Edit**

I should be able to log the execution of the job like start time, debug info, etc. that will be for my self.

Comment: Honestly, you need to clarify your logging requirements first - if you don't have any, you don't need any logging at all. If you have only a few, log4net may be oversized. Of course, **you** may have requirements by yourself for the purpose of debugging. Don't expect the community to **guess** your requirements for you - they will guess wrong.

Comment: Look at log4Net and look if it fits your need :)

Answer (score 11, accepted):

First, in general the answer is "the same way you'd do logging in any other application."

I would strongly recommend using something like log4net or nlog rather than rolling your own using a TextWriter for a number of reasons:

- There are great, free options out there that will probably result in you writing and maintaining less code -- just making logging target a configuration option is worth the price of admission alone.
- The great, free options are very performant -- logging is kind of easy until you get into "how do I log this without blocking the execution?"
- The great, free options are very reliable -- logging is easy until you get into "how do I make sure this fatal exception that killed the program gets flushed to the log?"

Comment: There is also [System.Diagnostics.TraceSource](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.diagnostics.tracesource.aspx) for logging if you want to stick to framework classes.  Attaching trace listeners can be done through code or app.config files.

Comment: @Sundeep: see what's going on here? Someone is *guessing* about your requirements: guess 1 "there are other applications with similar logging requirements", guess 2 "TextWriter" is not sufficient, guess 3 "logging needs to be configurable", guess 4 "logging may need to be non-blocking in the future", and so on. That's why I *dislike* such unspecific questions like yours.

Comment: @DocBrown : while I don't totally disagree, logging is a general problem and from the "I need more than Debug.Write() statement" level until you get to "I need to log a distributed multi-server process in one place" so I'm not sure how much specifics matter.

Comment: Don't get me wrong - I like your answer, and I think for a requirement like logging it is sometimes good to rely on experience with previous applications written in a comparable environment (so I agree especially with your first sentence). My critics goes to the OP, beeing too lazy or sloppy to analyse his situation and present that details in his question.

Answer (score 3):

**Short Answer:** There are different approaches to enable logging in C# .NET environment. For enterprise environment it is better to use a logging frameworks like **Log4Net, NLog, logger, etc..**

The quickest way would be logging through a simple method **Logger** to a plain **text file**. Like in a simple example provided  below:

```
private static void Logger(String lines)
{    
 // Write the string to a file.append mode is enabled so that the log
 // lines get appended to  test.txt than wiping content and writing the log

  using (var sw = new StreamWriter("c:\\test.txt",true))
     {
       file.WriteLine(lines);
     }
}
```

You may look for more details in  [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa287548%28v=vs.71%29.aspx).

**Note:**  It is strongly recommended to use a more robust approach (Logging framework + DB) if you are trying to log issues of a commercial application.

**References:**

- [Log4Net tutorial](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/140911/log4net-Tutorial)
- [NLog - Github](https://github.com/nlog/nlog/wiki/Tutorial)
- [loggr](http://loggr.net/go/cloud-service-for-net-logging)

Comment: What happens when that crashes before you flush?

Comment: @WyattBarnett it would not crash with slight modification.The previouse code sample was was using code in MSDN article. Thus, it is much safer now.

Comment: It would be fine if the main method catches a critical exception and handles writing out the results. Important to have that last line of defense with this approach."

Comment: @Rig sure that should be in place for an overall application design.